# wxPyDeprecationWarning in Python 3.5 (module 'wx' has no attribute 'Image_GetHandlers')

Tags: python, wxpython

Moving wxPython application from Python 2.5 to Python 3.5 and get this error

> AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'Image_GetHandlers'

Checked [Phoenix docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html) but there's a word MISSING in pace of this method.
Do yoou know any known workaraunds to replace Image_GetHandlers?

Python code:

```
handler_types = [handler.Type for handler in wx.Image_GetHandlers()]
wx.BITMAP_TYPE_SVG = max(handler_types) + 1
wx.BITMAP_TYPE_SVGZ = wx.BITMAP_TYPE_SVG + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper name for that method is actually `wx.Image.GetHandlers`, the version with the underscore was left-over from when Python did not have `staticmethod` and both names have been available ever since.

In Phoenix the static methods are real `staticmethods` and the underscore version have finally been dropped.  See https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#static-methods